# What is the use DOM in Salesforce where we can use that?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, css, dom

I have understood the abbrevation of DOM,but i am not understanding what is use of that in salesforce. Is there any link between xml and DOM.

Answer (score 5):

The DOM (DOM (Document Object Model) is just a model of the document. It could be a HTML/XHTML documents or XML document. The DOM only describes a structure of objects and it representation and accessibility.

- [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)
- [HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)
- [XML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/)
- [Javascript DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

In relation to Salesforce you have some ways where you can "use" DOM in Apex programming language and on the Visualforce pages.

In Apex the use of DOM is useful while creating or reading XML-documents. For that Apex language offers some classes:

- [What is Apex?](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm)
- [Document Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_document) - to process XML content
- [XmlNode Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode) - to work with a node in an XML document

Good XML and Apex examples could be found here: [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_dom.htm)

Other use case of the DOM in Salesforce is a Visualforce Page. It is like any other HTML page but processed all dynamic content on the server. When the page is loaded (rendered) completely - you can access page elements guided by DOM. For example manipulate the visibility, look & appearance with Javascript and CSS. For that you must have a strong understanding and knowledge of HTML, Javascript and CSS.

Some helpful topics:

- [An Introduction to Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce)
- [Best Practices for Accessing Visualforce Component IDs](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)
- [Using $Component to Reference Components from JavaScript](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_access.htm)